# Calling printf("%d") twice, const results

Tags: c, printf

I wrote the following program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
        printf("%x\n");
        printf("%x\n");
        return 0;
}
```

I know it is undefined behavior, I just check what happens. The compiler is gcc.

Sample output was:

```
541d3118
7ffffff7
```

Another sample output was:

```
e0b08078
7ffffff7
```

When I compiled it with `-O3` flag, the results were:

```
5ec20f18
9
```

And

```
3bedfa08
9
```

Why the first value change, but not the second value? Why is the second value different in high optimization level?

Comment: Undefined behavior: you need to add an `int` variable to `printf`.

Comment: I want an option to close questions with "undefined behaviour" as a reason.

Comment: @DevSolar Why? Trying to understand why the code works this way can be perfectly legitimate.

Comment: @glglgl: No it cannot, because the behaviour is **undefined**. That's the whole problem with these kind of questions. Yes I can spend a couple of minutes to explain why it does behave this way on **this** system with **this** compiler, and show off how cool I am for knowing this stuff -- but all that would achieve is that there are *more* people running around thinking that it just *might* be permissable to *exploit* such behaviour in productive code. Which it is not, full stop.

Comment: @DevSolar Then let me rephrase: "... why the code *acts* this way". It doesn't work, and should never be used this way. But it might as well be useful to the OP to know *why* it isn't defined. I'll rephrase my answer in this aspect.

Comment: Compile it with `-Wall -Werror` (Or equivalent `CFLAGS` on your compiler).

Comment: @glglgl: I see your angle. But *if* you want to answer an UB question "correctly", you'd have to talk about register passing, inline functions, upwards vs. downwards stacks, calling conventions, ... -- which is usually well beyond the grasp of someone asking such a question. That's why I have such a dim view on answering them in the first place. But to each his own. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar Here you are right. Strictly speaking, it can only be answered from within one situation and architecture. But that's to their very nature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try to see your question from an academic point of view. As you see, it is not reliable what you get (as always with undefined behaviour), and you should never rely on it.

But afaict you are interested in knowing why you see what you see.

Essentially, calling a function and passing arguments to it works via the stack. (This holds only for some architectures, not for all.)

A "regular call" to this function then could look like

```
push argument 2
push argument 1
call
```

If you are calling it as

```
push argument 1
call
```

the function sees as its 2nd argument something completely different, e. g. a return address or a local variable of the calling function or whatever else is currently on the stack.

So this value depends on what was on the stack earlier, and maybe even what you have as local variables, and other circumstances.

And, of course, it can as well depend on the optimization level chosen, as this controls which variables are put on the stack at the first place.

And that is exactly the reason why you shouldn't do that: you have *absolutely* no control over what you get here.

Answer (score 5):

You are calling `printf` without specifying a value where there is format specifier for it `%x`. This invokes undefined behavior, so what you observe may either be coincidence or implementation specific for your compiler. Either way invoking undefined behavior is never a good thing to have in your code.

Answer (score 2):

In a call to `printf`, according to the Standard, "*if there are insufficient arguments for the format, the behavior is undefined*". You are witnessing said behavior.